# Precision loss in numpy float32 conversion

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour when converting a scalar or array to numpy.float32. I suspect it's linked to the precision limit but can't exactly pinpoint where it's coming from. Here is an example with a scalar in IPython but I experienced the same thing with arrays in a script ran from command line:

```
In[25]: import numpy as np

In[26]: a=58289.16666

In[27]: a

Out[27]: 58289.16666

In[28]: b=np.float32(a)

In[29]: b

Out[29]: 58289.168
```

If I keep the same decimal precision but reduce the total number of significant digits for example with a = 5828.16666 then I got 1 more digit of precision, i.e. b = 5828.1665.
Any clue what's going on and how to keep the original precision while doing this conversion?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The native python float is the double, 'float64'.  `'float32' is only 4 bytes, and can't store as many digits.

Comment: Why do you want to do the conversion at all? You can freely use `a` in numpy all over and it will have 8 bytes at its disposal.

Comment: Assuming IEEE754 32  bit for float, it has 24 bits of effective significand, equivalent to about 7 decimal digits. Why are you using float?

Comment: "how to keep the original precision while doing this conversion". There's a simple answer: you can't. You're asking for something that's an explicitly precision-reducing operation to keep the same precision, and it doesn't do that. What's the _real_ problem you're trying to solve here? Why are you doing the `np.float32` conversion in the first place - what problem is it solving?